# Binding multiple ObservableCollections to One ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Have a bunch of `ObservableCollection<MeClass> Result` and require to combine them all into another `ObservableCollection<MeClass> AllResults` so I can display it in a `listview`.

Just not sure how to combine them all in one.

I Created a new class to combine them all but not sure how they will get updated after I got the list once... So not really sure which direction to take.

I know about `INotifyPropertyChanged` I'm just not sure how to combine them all and keep updating as everything changes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

.NET has a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) that allows you to treat multiple collections as a single collection. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so as long as your inner collections implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` as well (which in your case they certainly do), your bindings should work without any problems.

Usage example:

```
CompositeCollection cc = new CompositeCollection();
CollectionContainer container1 = new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Result1 }
CollectionContainer container2 = new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Result2 }
cc.Add(container1);
cc.Add(container2);
```

Comment: Note that you cannot use grouping with `CompositeCollectionView`. It's `CanGroup` is `false`, and its `ICollectionView.GroupDescriptions` property is `null` and is non-settable.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
public class CompositeCollection : ObservableCollection<MeClass>
{
    private ObservableCollection<MeClass> _subCollection1;
    private ObservableCollection<MeClass> _subCollection2;

    public CompositeCollection(ObservableCollection<MeClass> subCollection1, ObservableCollection<MeClass> subCollection2) 
    {
        _subCollection1 = subCollection1;
        _subCollection2 = subCollection2;

        AddSubCollections();
        SubscribeToSubCollectionChanges();
    }

    private void AddSubCollections()
    {
        AddItems(_subCollection1.All);
        AddItems(_subCollection2.All);
    }

    private void AddItems(IEnumerable<MeClass> items)
    {
        foreach (MeClass me in items)
            Add(me);
    }

    private void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<MeClass> items)
    {
        foreach (MeClass me in items)
            Remove(me);
    }

    private void SubscribeToSubCollectionChanges()
    {
        _subCollection1.CollectionChanged += OnSubCollectionChanged;
        _subCollection2.CollectionChanged += OnSubCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSubCollectionChanged(object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch(args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:    AddItems(args.NewItems.Cast<MeClass>());
                                                       break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove: RemoveItems(args.OldItems.Cast<MeClass>());
                                                       break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:  Clear();
                                                       AddSubCollections();
                                                       break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel - .NET already has a CompositeCollection (see my answer).

Comment: This approach works with grouping, unlike the framework's built-in `CompositeCollection`. Thanks. BTW the `All` symbols in `AddSubCollections` are compile errors.

Answer (score 4):

I reworked @GazTheDestroyer's answer into this (requires C# 7):

```
internal sealed class CompositeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public CompositeObservableCollection(INotifyCollectionChanged subCollection1, INotifyCollectionChanged subCollection2)
    {
        AddItems((IEnumerable<T>)subCollection1);
        AddItems((IEnumerable<T>)subCollection2);

        subCollection1.CollectionChanged += OnSubCollectionChanged;
        subCollection2.CollectionChanged += OnSubCollectionChanged;

        void OnSubCollectionChanged(object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    AddItems(args.NewItems.Cast<T>());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    RemoveItems(args.OldItems.Cast<T>());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    Clear();
                    AddItems((IEnumerable<T>)subCollection1);
                    AddItems((IEnumerable<T>)subCollection2);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    RemoveItems(args.OldItems.Cast<T>());
                    AddItems(args.NewItems.Cast<T>());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        void AddItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            foreach (var me in items)
                Add(me);
        }

        void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            foreach (var me in items)
                Remove(me);
        }
    }
}
```