# Is it possible to define a list of any type that implements multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
public interface X { void Foo(); }

public interface Y { void Bar(); }

public class A : X, Y
{
    public void Foo() {}
    public void Bar() {}
}

public class B : X, Y
{
    public void Foo() {}
    public void Bar() {}
}
```

Is there any way I can define a list (or any generic type for that matter) which can contain both `A`'s and `B`'s, while allowing me to treat the contents of said list as both `X` and `Y`? I.e. something that will allow me to write something along the lines of this:

```
var list = ???
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
list.First().Foo();
list.Last().Bar();
```

**Edit**

Just to clarify, the types I'm currently dealing with are [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`A`) and [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`B`), where the interfaces I'm interested in are `IList<T>` (`X`) and `INotifyCollectionChanged` (`Y`). Clearly I'm unable to change their class hierarchy to accomodate my needs, so I need a different workaround.

Comment: You could have `interface Z : X, Y {}`, but then `A` and `B` signature would have to change. Great question.

Comment: And here is a perfect example of why raw types in Java are still useful despite the existence of generics.

Comment: @Mehrdad Been a while since I used Java, but I believe with a raw list you'd still have to cast it every time you want to use it, no? It's easy to achieve the same by declaring it as List<object>, but I prefer some type safety.

Comment: This is an XY Problem - an inquiry on how to fix a broken solution rather than on what an appropriate solution is. What is your actual business requirement for which you believe this to be an appropriate solution?

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, that's exactly why they're useful: you *will* have to cast whatever you do, and using `List<Object>` would be wrong because these are not a list of objects -- they are a list of some type that is *not* expressible using generics. Hence you'd use a raw type and cast.

Comment: Couldn't you just declare `interface IComposite<T>:IList<T>,INotifyCollectionChanged` and make `A` and `B` derive from `IComposite<T>`, or did I misunderstand which part of the code above can be changed?

Comment: How would you get type safety even with a list that can only contain `A` or `B` without casting retrieved elements to either one of them?

Comment: @Steven: perhaps you can clarify what your exact situation is because what you are trying to do is plain non-statically typed programming. Might as well just use `List<dynamic>`. The fact that they're different types often indicates they shouldn't be in the same list in the first place.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't necessarily want to only have it contain A's and B's, but objects of any type that implements both interfaces.

Comment: @Steven: I feel like I'm reading contradictory things in your post. Do you want the object to implement *any one* of the interfaces in the set, or *all* of them?

Comment: So just to be clear: your list should contain objects of types that implement both A and B?

Comment: @Steven: Please explain **why** you believe this is necessary in your application.

Comment: @Mehrdad BOTH interfaces. Someone edited my title incorrectly, and I screwed up at rolling back that edit.

Comment: @Pieter I have a bunch of data sources (typically `ObservableCollection<T>` and `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`), and I want to create a class which takes a bunch of these sources (for the same T) and 1. reads its contents (hence requiring `IList<T>`) and 2. listens to changes (hence requiring `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Comment: Okay then in that case @PieterGeerkens I think it's not an XY problem. :) Seems perfectly reasonable... e.g. a `Comparable` `List`.

Comment: @Mehrdad Java actually has intersection types - you can use & in generics in Java so this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Maybe [`CompositeCollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203795/binding-multiple-observablecollections-to-one-observablecollection/13205040#13205040) would meet your needs?  It's untyped, but is an overall collection that listens for changes to other collections.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Wow, I stand corrected! I had no idea they were introduced in version 7. Nice, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: What about defining a wrapper type that can be constructed from either interface; and make the collection of that wrapper type.

Comment: AFAIK it's possible in Scala.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, unless you declare another interface:

```
IAB : IA, IB {}
```

and make both classes implement it.

You could also implement your own collection class, something like `List<IFirst, ISecond>`, which would allow that.

Comment: I'm not able to change the classes (will edit question to clarify). Making a custom collection seems like a reasonable idea, I'll try that out later if no one else comes up with something better.

Comment: You don't have to change the classes. You can create a wrapper classes around them.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely you don't want to modify the class A and B
So a wrapper will do the job

```
public class XYWrapper : X, Y
{

  private dynamic InternalObject { get; set; }

  public void Foo() { InternalObject.Foo(); }
  public void Bar() { InternalObject.Bar(); }

  public static implicit operator XYWrapper(A value)
  {
    var instance = new XYWrapper();
    instance.InternalObject = value;
    return instance;
  }

  public static implicit operator XYWrapper(B value)
  {
    var instance = new XYWrapper();
    instance.InternalObject = value;
    return instance;
  }
}
```

So you use it in this way:

```
var list = new List<XYWrapper>();
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
list.First().Foo();
list.Last().Bar();
```

Comment: This won't require the types to implement both `X` and `Y`.

Comment: I get excited whenever I see a use for `dynamic`

Comment: I think `dynamic` is overkill in this solution, since you already know only `Foo` and `Bar` will ever be called from the object. Why not store it as just `object` and cast as needed?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Yes, you are right. But I think it is one of the safe scenario to use `dynamic` because it is private and for known type A and B only. The `InternalObject` should have Foo() and Bar() and you don't need to mind which interface to cast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you implement them entirely [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public interface IBar
{
}

public class DualList : IList<IFoo>, IList<IBar>
{
    List<IFoo> list1 = new List<IFoo>();
    List<IBar> list2 = new List<IBar>();

    #region IList<IFoo> Members

    int IList<IFoo>.IndexOf(IFoo item)
    {
        return list1.IndexOf(item);
    }

    // Etc etc

    #endregion

    #region IList<IBar> Members

    int IList<IBar>.IndexOf(IBar item)
    {
        return list2.IndexOf(item);
    }

    // Etc etc

    #endregion
}
```

This container acts acts as two independent lists of different types.  To use, you can cast it like so:

```
((IList<IFoo>)dualList).Add(item);
```

I question the wisdom of this, however.  You will definitely have trouble serializing such a list with any known serializer.

Comment: Rolled back title edit as I don't believe it correctly reflected my question. I think your answer is relevant, although I totally agree that it doesn't look very wise.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare,

```
public class SomeType<T> where T: X, Y
{
    public void Do(T t)
    {
        t.Foo();
        t.Bar();
    }
}
```

like [here](https://ideone.com/atrjEd), you'll know that `T` must implement both `X` and `Y` because of the generic type constraints.

However, when you come to instantiate `SomeType` you'll need a single type that both `A` and `B` inherit or implement.

If you simply add,

```
interface Z : X, Y { }
```

then change `A` and `B` to implement `Z`

```
public class A : Z
{
    public void Foo() {}
    public void Bar() {}
}

public class B : Z
{
    public void Foo() {}
    public void Bar() {}
}
```

you can simply use `Z` as the generic type.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a composite interface of your two interfaces:

```
interface IA
{
    void Foo();
}
interface IB
{
    void Bar();
}
interface IAB:IA,IB{}
```

Now take your two classes:

```
class A:IA,IB
{
    public void Foo(){}
    public void Bar(){}
}

class B:IA,IB
{
    public void Foo(){}
    public void Bar(){}
}
```

and create subclasses that implement the composite interface (no actual implementation is required as it's already present for both interfaces in the composite interface):

```
class AX:A,IAB
{
}
class BX:B,IAB
{
}
```

Now you can...

```
void Main()
{
    List<IAB> list=new List<IAB>();
    list.Add(new AX());
    list.Add(new BX());
}
```

Comment: In his concrete situation he has no control over the interfaces nor the implementing classes.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense because the number of possible combinations is exponential in the number of interfaces. Do you really expect there to be an interface for every combo?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel So above, the framework (unchangeable) interfaces/classes would be IA, IB, A and B. These would remain unchanged. By creating subclasses of A and B that implement the composite interface (also non-framework), you can have a list of items with the common behaviours as now they all satisfy a common interface.

Comment: @Mehrdad I thought we were talking about 2 specific interfaces, `IList<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. The number of combinations of these two items is very low. (!)

Comment: @spender for my current situation yes, it's only those two. But I agree with Mehrdad that a more extensible solution would be nicer.

Comment: @spender: ah right, I looked past that. Looks like this will work indeed but at this point I would cut my losses and drop the statically typed requirement and just go with `dynamic`. Or, preferably, revise the system altogether of course.

Comment: Yes, it seems that c# is ill suited to this particular problem... will be watching this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: There is nothing dynamic about the typing here, you're going in the wrong direction. Not only is it conceptually wrong but dynamic would be unnecessarily slow as well.

Comment: @spender: That was a minor edit to the question, I couldn't care less what the interfaces were! The question itself is great and valid, and not an XY problem.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm not saying anything is. I'm saying it probably should be. If you have a situation where you need to distinct types in one collection, it's hard to justify creating 4 intermediate types that have no value but to aggregate other types. Dynamic might keep the code elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have different concrete types in a list, each implementing a different interface(potentially inclusive or mutually exclusive), then you need to test for each interface which is often done using `instance as ISomeInterface` and checking if the result is non-null.

Note the below will work for types which implement both IFooable and IBarrable, or just implement one of the two.  So it gives you alot of flexibility while remaining type safe.  The only downside is it is possible for a concrete type to implement the marker interface directly and not implement IFooable or IBarrable at all.

```
// marker interface
public interface IFooBar
{
}

public interface IFooable:IFooBar
{ void Foo(); }

public interface IBarrable:IFooBar
{ void Bar(); }


public class FooBarProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFooBars(IList<IFooBar> foobars)
    {
        foreach(var foobar in foobars)
        {
           // feature detection to see which interfaces the instance implements
           IBarrable bar = foobar as IBarrable;
           if(bar != null)
               bar.Bar();

           IFooable foo = foobar as IFooable;
           if(foo != null)
               foo.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have no control over your interfaces, then you can use `List<object>` which is somewhat less type safe, but still us the `foobar as IBarrable` technique.

If you still want to leverage the marker interface to constrain the IList a bit more, you can wrap the interface you can't change with an interface of your making like so, where IOutOfMyControlFooable is whatever interface you can't change:

```
public interface IFooable : IFooBar, IOutOfMyControlFooable
{ void Foo(); }

public interface IBarrable : IFooBar, IOutOfMyControlBarrable
{ void Bar(); }

public class FooBarProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFooBars(IList<IFooBar> foobars)
    {
        foreach(var foobar in foobars)
        {
           // feature detection to see which interfaces the instance implements
           IBarrable bar = foobar as IBarrable;
           if(bar != null)
               bar.Bar();

           IFooable foo = foobar as IFooable;
           if(foo != null)
               foo.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer my question. I'm not interested to treat the objects as their specific type, but to have multiple interfaces.

Comment: @Steven I'm not checking for specific type.  I am checking for an interface.  If it implements both `IFooable` and `IBarrable`, then **both** `.Foo()` and `.Bar()` will be executed.

Comment: I see, I misread that. In any case, my interfaces don't share a common base interface, so I can't declare a `IList<IFooBar>` (it's exactly this declaration that my question is about).

Comment: @Steven Like many of the other answers, that requirement results in  wrapping the types that are out of your control to abstract them away.  I've updated my answer with one option using my technique.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper type like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T>() {
    public WrapperObsCollection(ObservableCollection<T> collection) {
      IsReadOnly      = false;
      ObsCollection   = collection;
      ROObsCollection = null;
    }
    public WrapperObsCollection(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> collection : base {
      IsReadOnly      = true;
      ObsCollection   = null;
      ROObsCollection = collection;
    }

    public bool                            IsReadOnly        { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<T>         ObsCollection     { get; private set; }
    public ReadOnlyObsrevableCollection<T> ROObsCollection   { get; private set; }
}
```

-- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an additional class like this ...

```
public class ABList<T> : List<T> where T : X, Y
{
    // implement me
}
```

... and use it like this?

```
var list = new ABList<dynamic>(); // issue here; see comment below
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
list.First().Foo();
list.Last().Bar();
```

**UPDATE**: Solution doesn't work due to a compiler issue (thanks @mikez). If the type check is of no concern the solution can be optimized to just use a dynamic list like this:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
list.First().Foo();
list.Last().Bar();
```

Comment: Is there any need for the additional class if you're going to use `dynamic` anyway?

Comment: This one will only allow you to store instances of certain type that implements both `X` and `Y`, not any type that implements them both.

Comment: It ensures you can use the interfaces X and Y only. That's the only reason. If you don't care this list is not needed of course.

Comment: This won't compile. `dynamic` does not satisfy the type constraint.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Yes, I've tried it and [it doesn't compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4oJrkH).

Comment: @mikez Thanks for this response. Indeed, it doesn't. I was locally working with `var list = new List<dynamic>();` which is different to my code suggestion. So what can be done is this: `var list = new List<dynamic>();`. It will work, but it doesn't satisfy the type check. I'll update my answer. Response appreciated!